# Touchpad functionalities to laptop

Tags: touchscreen, kylin

I recently purchased a Lenovo Flex 3, a laptop that has touch screen capabilities. Currently I am running Ubuntu Kylin 15.04, and I was wanting to try to add the Touch functions to my system without installing a new version of Ubuntu. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: What touch function you would like to add?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, with the release of 15.04 Ubuntu touch screen and touch pad support has been upgraded and works fairly well.  I don't like touch scrfeens ands touch pads, so I have no first-hand knowledge I can offer you.